# Relationship Query issue

Tags: soql, relationships, .net

i need your help to understand my problem with a relationship query.

I want to get all users with the role "ceo" so i tested the following query in the [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/):

```
SELECT Id,Email,Name FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name = 'CEO'
```

this will return the expected result, but if i'm running this query in my .net application it throws an exception

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: SOQL statements can't query related data
```

I do not understand where the problem is and searching for the error message doesn't help. I also tested the example query (`SELECT Contact.FirstName, Contact.Account.Name from Contact`) from [Understanding Relationship Names](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding) with the same result.

I hope you can help me with this annoying problem :(

```
public static List<User> UsersFromSalesforce(Salesforce.SforceService client, string group)
{
    logger.Info("loading records...");
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    Salesforce.QueryResult qr = null;

    try
    {
        //string query = string.Format("SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name = '{0}'", group);
        string query = "SELECT Id,Email,Name FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name = 'CEO'";

        qr = client.query(query);
        if (qr.size > 0)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < qr.records.Length; i++)
                {
                    Salesforce.User p = (Salesforce.User)qr.records[i];
                    users.Add(new User(p));
                }
                if (qr.done)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    qr = client.queryMore(qr.queryLocator);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    logger.Info("{0} records loaded", users.Count);
    return users;
}
```

Comment: You're using an old API version, update the WSDL you're using.

Comment: i'm using an updated WSDL and api v34.0

Comment: check your code that is managing login, your query request seems to be going to an old API version.

Comment: was your test with workbench against the same org/credentials?

Comment: damn, sometimes you should quadruple check what you are doing :( i've checked the endpoint url in the WSDL and found out that it was generated against v35.0 ... i do not understand why `SELECT Id,Email,Name FROM User` works and the other query not but after fixing this everything works properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**double check your endpoints**

Working against v34 and generate an wsdl with v35 (accidentally) will not work properly
I do not understand why some querys will work, some not and the api response is so "cryptic" but after fixing the endpoint missmatch everything will work fine

See [Relationship Query issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106624/relationship-query-issue#comment145850_106624)